# Multi level menu angular 2 Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to create multi level menu angular 2 material a like [here](https://codepen.io/abhishekpabba/pen/NrRJVW/) (angular js)

```
<md-button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu()">Link1</md-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3rd party library for angular2 and above versions, named as PrimeNG components. They are very simple and useful .

You can see some of the menu types as you want

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/megamenu

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/menubar

These components and modules are very flexible in usage of class and style directives.

Please see the above examples.

Comment: Look like this not responsive, I need to finish it yourself?